# htaccess Rewrite Rule - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am having problems getting what I think should be a simple htaccess rewrite to work...

Current URL: http://www.website.com/profile.php?id=61338848

Desired URL: http://www.website.com/61338848

Current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Result from the above htaccess is `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR:`

I would also like it to work for a custom domain (if set) although I am sure the solution priovided for the above will work just as well.

Desired URL: http://www.website.com/customdomain

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this `.htaccess` and it works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag is used, that you can add multiple get parameters like this: `http://www.website.com/61338848?parameter=value`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` checks if the `request_filename` is a file, if yes, the `RewriteRule` will not be executed

Comment: perfect, I don't know if you edited it but this works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `/` before the filename, like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It worked for me.

Comment: that sends me straight to the profile page rather than the homepage but does stop the internal server error